# How to sort a list lexicographical?

Tags: java

I have a list that I made with a type I created of . I want to sort it in lexicographical order. I have seen the `compareTo` in Java, am I supposed to use this? I'm not sure how to put it into the lexographical format from a list? Can anyone show me an example? I have seen many examples, but I am not sure how to do it from a list.

Comment: What does your Type look like? Generally I'd use a `Comparator`.

Comment: If the type of list is String then simply use Collections.sort method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use implement the `Comparable<Type>` in your own `Type` class and implement the `compareTo` method to match the lexicographical order. Than just call `Collections.sort(yourlistOfTypes)`.